# JSON Search and remove in php?

Tags: php, json

I have a session variable `$_SESSION["animals"]` containing a deep json object with values:

```
$_SESSION["animals"]='{
"0":{"kind":"mammal","name":"Pussy the Cat","weight":"12kg","age":"5"},
"1":{"kind":"mammal","name":"Roxy the Dog","weight":"25kg","age":"8"},
"2":{"kind":"fish","name":"Piranha the Fish","weight":"1kg","age":"1"},
"3":{"kind":"bird","name":"Einstein the Parrot","weight":"0.5kg","age":"4"}
}';
```

For example, I want to find the line with "Piranha the Fish" and then remove it (and json_encode it again as it was).
How to do this? I guess i need to search in `json_decode($_SESSION["animals"],true)` resulting array and find the parent key to remove but i'm stucked anyways.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`json_decode` will turn the JSON object into a PHP structure made up of nested arrays. Then you just need to loop through them and `unset` the one you don't want.

```
<?php
$animals = '{
 "0":{"kind":"mammal","name":"Pussy the Cat","weight":"12kg","age":"5"},
 "1":{"kind":"mammal","name":"Roxy the Dog","weight":"25kg","age":"8"},
 "2":{"kind":"fish","name":"Piranha the Fish","weight":"1kg","age":"1"},
 "3":{"kind":"bird","name":"Einstein the Parrot","weight":"0.5kg","age":"4"}
 }';

$animals = json_decode($animals, true);
foreach ($animals as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array('Piranha the Fish', $value)) {
        unset($animals[$key]);
    }
}
$animals = json_encode($animals);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! And how to do this if I don't know the key name?

Comment: It is not the better solution if one does not know the key name.

Comment: @moogeek: Do you mean "kind", "name", "weight" and "age" in this case? If you don't know that, you'll need to introduce another layer of iteration, looping through `$value` and checking each sub-value against your string. If you find it, `unset($animals[$key])` will work as it does above, and you can then break out of the loop. I've added this code to my answer.

Comment: I've just realised it's much easier with `in_array`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra comma at the end of the last element in your JSON. Remove it and `json_decode` will return an array. Simply loop through it, test for string, then unset the element when found.

If you need the final array reindexed, simply pass it to [array_values](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php 
<?php

    function remove_json_row($json, $field, $to_find) {

        for($i = 0, $len = count($json); $i < $len; ++$i) {
            if ($json[$i][$field] === $to_find) {
                array_splice($json, $i, 1); 
            }   
        }   

        return $json;
    }   

    $animals =
'{
"0":{"kind":"mammal","name":"Pussy the Cat","weight":"12kg","age":"5"},
"1":{"kind":"mammal","name":"Roxy the Dog","weight":"25kg","age":"8"},
"2":{"kind":"fish","name":"Piranha the Fish","weight":"1kg","age":"1"},
"3":{"kind":"bird","name":"Einstein the Parrot","weight":"0.5kg","age":"4"}
}';

    $decoded = json_decode($animals, true);

    print_r($decoded);

    $decoded = remove_json_row($decoded, 'name', 'Piranha the Fish');

    print_r($decoded);

?>
```