# search within json with php

Tags: php, json

Here's the json code :

```
"Results":[{"username":"test","password":"test"},{"username":"test","password":"test"},{"username":"google","password":"test"},{"username":"yahoo","password":"test"}]}
```

You can see that it contains multiple values. I want to search within this code.

I want to get password of username : google

Is there any way to do that using php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON Search and remove in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901562/json-search-and-remove-in-php)

Comment: but how to do that with this json code ?

Comment: @ Jakub username and password is just a test variable :)

Answer (score 3):

The json code is a data representation.  You can either treat it as a string, and use php's string parsing functions to get what you need, or you can load this into an array or an object.  I will focus on the array approach, as it maintains the structure the JSON was intended to represent.  There is a function [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/json_decode) which will take your json and turn it into an array:

```
$jsondata = '{"Results":[{"username":"test","password":"test"},
             {"username":"test","password":"test"},
             {"username":"google","password":"test"},
             {"username":"yahoo","password":"test"}]}';
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

Once you have this array, you can loop through it to find the value you want:

```
foreach($jsonArray["Results"] as $user) {
    if($user['username'] == 'google') {
        echo "Password = " . $user['password'];
    }
}
```

That should pretty much handle your case.  Note that your JSON is missing a "{" Before the "Results" element, you can go [here to validate](http://jsonlint.com/)  your JSON code before running json_decode on it.

Answer (score 2):

From the php manual :

```
<?php
$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345
?>
```

Then you could make a loop on the object ($obj) with test case (if/else) or switch case

Comment: using if/else can be slow as searching from 100s of results :) any substitute ?

Comment: +1. But note that you will be able to traverse only one level deep with that. To access deeper level you'll have to chain that: $obj->{'level1'}->{'level2'}->{'level3'}

Comment: switch case if faster than if/else , more info here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97987/switch-vs-if-else

Comment: and here the how to implement it http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php