# How do I remove an Attribute from a JSON String utilizing PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON result in PHP that looks like the following:

```
[{"attributes":{"type":"Manager__c","url":"/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Manager__c/a03U00000015ay6IAA"},"Id":"a03U00000015ay6IAA","Name":"ManagerID-00003"},

{"attributes":{"type":"Manager__c","url":"/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Manager__c/a03U00000015ZfJIAU"},"Id":"a03U00000015ZfJIAU","Name":"ManagerID-00001"},

{"attributes":{"type":"Manager__c","url":"/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Manager__c/a03U00000015axwIAA"},"Id":"a03U00000015axwIAA","Name":"ManagerID-00002"}]
```

I want to eliminate the Attributes (which contains Type and URL) so that the JSON result is flattened. So I'd like it to look more like:

```
[{"Id":"a03U00000015ay6IAA","Name":"ManagerID-00003"},
{"Id":"a03U00000015ay6IAA","Name":"ManagerID-00003"},
{"Id":"a03U00000015ay6IAA","Name":"ManagerID-00003"}]
```

What is the best way in PHP to eliminate every instance of attributes?

Comment: What I would do would be to `json_decode()` it, loop through and build a new array with only the attributes you want, and then `json_encode()` when you're done.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901562/json-search-and-remove-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//assign the orignal string to variable $json
$json = '[{"attributes":{"type":"Manager__c","url":"/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Manager__c/a03U00000015ay6IAA"},"Id":"a03U00000015ay6IAA","Name":"ManagerID-00003"},{"attributes":{"type":"Manager__c","url":"/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Manager__c/a03U00000015ZfJIAU"},"Id":"a03U00000015ZfJIAU","Name":"ManagerID-00001"},{"attributes":{"type":"Manager__c","url":"/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Manager__c/a03U00000015axwIAA"},"Id":"a03U00000015axwIAA","Name":"ManagerID-00002"}]';
//decode the string with json_decode();
$decoded = json_decode($json);
//loop over the decoded array and populate array with Id and Name only
foreach($decoded as $d) $newarr[] = array('Id' => $d->Id, 'Name' => $d->Name);
//json encode the resulting array.
$finalJSON = json_encode($newarr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) should be easy enough:

```
function strip_arguments( $item){
  $new_result = array(
    'Id' => $item['Id'],
    'Name' => $item['Name'],
  )
  return $new_result;
}

$array = json_decode( $input);
$array = array_map( 'strip_arguments', $array);
$input = json_encode( $array);
```

You of course may use [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) inside `strip_arguments` (instead of creating new array) but this will make sure any "new attribute" won't make it trough.

<sub>You can use `return array(...)` instead of declaring variable and chain operations to: `json_encode(array_map( 'strip_arguments', json_decode( $input)));` too :)</sub>

Comment: Liking the solution so far, however I got the following error happening

Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's JSON's tools you can convert the JSON string into an array, from here use a simple foreach statement and REGEX to delete array entries.

Once this is done simply convert back into a JSON string using PHP functions and do with it as you please :-)

The functions I am thinking off are - json_decode, json_encode.

Thanks
Andrew