# Javascript delete JSON elements

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have this JSON string in a PHP page:

```
{
  "elements": [{
    "type": "pie",
    "alpha": 0.3,
    "animate": [{
      "type": "fade"
    }, {
      "type": "bounce",
      "distance": 5
    }],
    "start-angle": 0,
    "tip": "#val# de #total# #percent#",
    "colours": ["#d01f3c", "#356aa0", "#C79810"],
    "values": [{
      "value": 1,
      "label": "procesador amd sempron 140"
    }, {
      "value": 1,
      "label": "procesador sempron le130"
    }, {
      "value": 1,
      "label": "procesador amd a4-3300 x2"
    }, {
      "value": 1,
      "label": "procesador intel celeron g530"
    }]
  }],
  "title": {
    "text": "Procesadores, Reinicio",
    "style": "color: #356aa0; font-size: 20px"
  },
  "bg_colour": "#FFFFFF",
  "x_axis": null
}
```

I call it like this:

```
$.getJSON("restart_proce.php", function(json)
{    
console.log(json);
```

I need to transform it to this:

```
[{\"value\": 1, \"label\": \"procesador amd sempron 140\" }, { \"value\": 1, \"label\": \"procesador sempron le130\" }, { \"value\": 1, \"label\": \"procesador amd a4-3300 x2\" }, { \"value\": 1, \"label\": \"procesador intel celeron g530\" } ]
```

I'm trying to delete elements like this:

```
delete json.elements[3];
```

but it doesn't delete anything. How can I make it work?

Comment: I think you are looking for [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901562/json-search-and-remove-in-php

Comment: `delete` will set that array element to undefined, but it will not remove the element. Use `splice` instead. Ofcourse, in this example there is only 1 element in that `elements` array, so `json.elements[3]` is accessing nothing.

Comment: There only seems to be one element in the array contained in the `elements` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the values directly before `console.log(json)`

```
json= json.elements[0].values
```

Or in the `restart_proce.php` php page just echo

```
echo json_encode($data['elements'][0]['values']); // if associative array is used.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
json.elements.splice(3, 1);
```

See: [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 2):

**Removing an item from an Array:**

There are several ways. The **[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** method is the most versatile:

```
data.items.splice(3, 1); // Removes three items starting with the 2nd,
```

splice modifies the original array, and returns an array of the items you removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = {"result":[
  {"FirstName":"Test1","LastName":"User","Email":"test@test.com","City":"ahmedabad","State":"sk","Country":"canada","Status":"False","iUserID":"23"},
  {"FirstName":"user","LastName":"user","Email":"u@u.com","City":"ahmedabad","State":"Gujarat","Country":"India","Status":"True","iUserID":"41"},
  {"FirstName":"Ropbert","LastName":"Jones","Email":"Robert@gmail.com","City":"NewYork","State":"gfg","Country":"fgdfgdfg","Status":"True","iUserID":"48"},
  {"FirstName":"hitesh","LastName":"prajapti","Email":"hitesh.prajapati@phptalent.com","City":"","State":"","Country":"","Status":"True","iUserID":"78"}
  ]
}
alert(data.result);
delete data.result[3];
alert(data.result);
```

working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Djc4h/)

or You can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove elements from an array.

Comment: Won't work as it sets the element to undefined. There are "freak" situations in which this works though, so it shouldn't be trusted.